# SharePoint Design package breaks App's master-page

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-branding

I've created a design package for custom look & feel in SharePoint 2013 sites. After importing the package if I visit SharePoint hosted apps, master-page seem to be broken.

[image]

I've tried to fix master-page using below PowerShell but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null ) {
         Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}
Start-SPAssignment -Global 

$SelectedPortalUrl = "Site-URL"


# loop all webs that are APPs
Get-SPSite $SelectedPortalUrl | Get-SPWeb -Limit All -filter { $_.Template -eq "APP" } | Foreach-Object {

    $_.MasterUrl = $_.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/app.master"
    $_.CustomMasterUrl = $_.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/masterpage/app.master"
    #Write-Host $_.MasterUrl
    #Write-Host $_.CustomMasterUrl
    #Write-Host "Fixed: " $_.Name -Fore Green
}

Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

How can I ensure that design package doesn't change app's master-page?

Edit: Observation - If I directly deploy app to developer site, this breaks. If I use app update method & push newer version to app catalog, issue doesn't replicate.

Comment: just to make sure you created the design package using publishing features like here ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862342.aspx
Your script looks fine to me, and paying attention to your screenshot it looks more like one (or many) of you CSS have been overwritten by the design package.

Comment: @baywet, Yes, I've created package using mentioned steps. Yes, I fear the same. Is there a way to avoid design manager package not to apply the branding to app?